# Enabling external aborts on an ARM CPU

Tags: embedded, arm

From the [Cortex-R reference manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0363g/I31997.html), <sup>probably not Cortex-R specific</sup>

> **Asynchronous abort masking**
>
> The nature of asynchronous aborts means that they can occur while the processor is handling a different abort. If an asynchronous abort generates a new exception in such a situation, the `r14_abt` and `SPSR_abt` values are overwritten. If this occurs before the data is pushed to the stack in memory, the state information about the first abort is lost. To prevent this from happening, the CPSR contains a mask bit, the A-bit, to indicate that an asynchronous abort cannot be accepted. When the A-bit is set, any asynchronous abort that occurs is held pending by the processor until the A-bit is cleared, when the exception is actually taken. The A-bit is automatically set when abort, IRQ or FIQ exceptions are taken, and on reset. You must only clear the A-bit in an abort handler after the state information has either been stacked to memory, or is no longer required.

My question is, if I have the `A` bit masked since reset how can I know if an *asynchronous abort* is pending?  Can pending external aborts be cleared without unmasking the `A` bit and taking the exception?  Or more generally, is there advice on clearing the `A` bit after a reset?

Apparently something in my current boot chain has a pending external abort (but only after a hard power on).  I would like to enable the external aborts, but it seems rather cumbersome to *special case* the first *external abort* in the exception code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a system that implements the security extensions, the Interrupt Status Register, ISR, can tell you if there's an external abort pending. Sadly this doesn't help much if you're on R4 which doesn't implement them.

Otherwise, there's nothing that I can see in the architecture to identify or deal with an abort short of taking the exception as you say. This doesn't really surprise me - in general an external about that can be safely ignored very much *is* a special case.

If the bug in the system can't be fixed (is the bootloader probing devices in the wrong order, or similar?) then a workaround, however cumbersome, is the order of the day - if there's some reasonably straightforward way to tell a cold boot from a warm reset I can imagine a pretty trivial self-contained shim to handle it so the main code never needs to know.